# how do i add pug auto-indentation in vsCode

Tags: html, pug, auto-indent

[auto-indentation like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggzGR.gif)
is there a way to add auto-indentation support for pug files in vsCode this is normal in sublime and atom

Comment: This is an open issue in see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/65044